# how to draw this curve on bottom navigation

Tags: flutter

how to draw this curve on  bottom navigation using flutter I don know to how make it with flutter I know to make bottom navigation bar but this curve no idea I hope some advise there is the image I hope some tutorial
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8zeG.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to ClipPath around a BottomAppBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800297/is-there-a-way-to-clippath-around-a-bottomappbar)